# Fail if condition function is undefined

Tags: bash, if-statement, undefined-function

Suppose I use a function in an if statement:

```
if isSomeConditionTrue; then
  echo "true";
else
  echo "false";
fi
```

This works fine if `isSomeConditionTrue` is defined.

However, if `isSomeConditionTrue` is not defined, e.g. due to a typo or a missing import, it evaluates to `"false"` rather than failing.

[`set -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This is a debugging issue; make sure `isSomeConditionTrue` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to insert this before your `if`:

```
command_not_found_handle () { false; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work on older versions of Bash.

Comment: This also just replaces the normal exit status of 127 with an exit status of 1. If using a new-enough version of `bash`, setting `command_not_found_handle` to actually *exit* the shell might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you just need debug your script and ensure you have the appropriate imports and don't make typos. That said, there is a way to distinguish between an undefined command and a normal failure, although it's not probably something you want to use throughout your script.

```
isSomeConditionTrue
case $? in
  127) echo "Command not found" ;;
  0) echo "Command succeeds" ;;
  *) echo "Some other problem" ;;
esac
```

An exit status of 127 means the command was not found. (Note that this implies a well-behaved program should not return a status of 127 itself; consider the return value reserved.)

Comment: Informative, but too verbose to use, especially when combining multiple condition functions.